# Meaning of JavaScript form validation code?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have to explain how a specific Javascript code validates a web form, but I am stuck with what some of the features do, most specifically this section of the code. I understand that the first line defines that the rest of the section should only run if the field `Field1` of the form `ExampleForm` is left empty, but I do not know what purpose the rest of the code serves. All I know is that `msg` is a variable created earlier in the document with an empty default value, and that `result` is another variable with a default value of true. Can anyone help me out by explaining what each line does?

```
if (document.ExampleForm.Field1.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your name \n";
document.ExampleForm.name.focus();
document.getElementById('Field1').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
```

Comment: Note that [curved quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_Unicode), as you've posted here, aren't valid [string literal delimiters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

In plain english:

If the document form field value is equal to an empty string, set the error message to `msg`, then focus  on the element, and give is a red color so the user knows it's an error, and set the result to false, for whatever you're going to use that for later in your code/function.

Comment: Even though this is an overview, OP asked for a line by line description of what the code does.

Comment: It's literally a line by line explanation..?

Comment: Sorry I guess I was just being picky with his language.

Comment: It does not set the error message, it appends. It also appends in a way that won't display multiple messages properly outside of a `<pre>` element

Answer (score 0):

So this would in part depend on what other code is on the page. For example `document.ExampleForm` is not part of the DOM and seems to be something someone kludged onto your page.

Overall I would say this is pretty bad code that makes a ton of assumptions that won't necessarily hold up written by someone who doesn't understand in-browser javascript very well, but let's go with it

```
//if the value in this variable is falsy (false, empty, or 0)
if (document.ExampleForm.Field1.value=="") {
    //Append this to the msg string. Note \n is usually used 
    //to indicate "new line" but wont' do anything on the web since that's not how line breaks
    //work on the web
    msg+=”You must enter your name \n”;
    //Invoke the `focus` field on this variable. From the context I assume this is
    //a DOM node so you are basically focusing it in the browser
    document.ExampleForm.name.focus();
    //Set the font color of '#Field1' to red
    document.getElementById('Field1').style.color=”red”;
    //Presumably result is something that tells you true/false did the validation succeed.
    //set it to false to indicate failure.
    result = false;
}
```

My guess about what `document.ExampleForm` is that it depends on some undocumented behavior of an old browser to add anything with `id=ExampleForm` to the document element. But really I have no idea. Maybe you have some code elsewhere that creates that variable. Either way its a horrible idea and should get someone yelled at.

Comment: sorry - an error on my part with the exampleform and examentry! i've just amended the code

Comment: Ok, answer adjusted but the specifics are all the same